# Pulling Data from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

Have two files

1. Contains data of products
2. Contains Packaging Details

The file containing Packaging Details  has details OF Packaging of product which runs into more than 2 line items.

Will explain , Sheet 1 contains the following Details

```
Product Code    Name            Pincode
370419466   Tejal Enterprise    401209
370419440   Tejal Enterprise    401209
```

Sheet 2 contains the following Data

```
Prodcut Code    MODEL                  LENTH    WIDTH   HIGHT
370419466   ECU0550BD, W/ UVM2000      186       40      36 
370419466   ECU0550BD, W/ UVM2000      53        33      43 
370419466   ECU0550BD, W/ UVM2000      184       46      24
370419440   ECU0900BD                  186       40      36     
370419440   ECU0900BD                  53        33      43
```

**REQUIREMENT IS TO COLLATE DATE IN SHEET 3 as follows**

```
Product Code    Name          Pincode  LENTH    WIDTH   HIGHT
370419466   Tejal Enterprise    401209   186    40      36
370419466   Tejal Enterprise    401209   53     33      43
370419466   Tejal Enterprise    401209   184    46      24
370419440   Tejal Enterprise    401209   186    40      36
370419440   Tejal Enterprise    401209    53    33      43
```

**REQUIREMENT IS TO COLLATE DATE IN SHEET 3 as follows**

```
Product Code    Name           Pincode  LENTH   WIDTH   HIGHT
370419466   Tejal Enterprise    401209   186     40     36
370419466   Tejal Enterprise    401209   53      33     43
370419466   Tejal Enterprise    401209   184     46     24
370419440   Tejal Enterprise    401209   186     40     36
370419440   Tejal Enterprise    401209    53     33     43
```

Tried `Vlookup` and Filter formula but not able to get the above result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CREATE DATA BASED DATA FROM 2 DIFFERENT SHEETS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76160289/create-data-based-data-from-2-different-sheets)

Answer (score 0):

This is a data structure issue, not a formula issue. Because your keys are not unique there’s nothing that would cause the formula to proceed beyond the first match.

Consider adding another field with a `model_size` ID or giving different sizes of the same product different ID #’s